# popen with python read and write blocks, python2.7

Tags: python, subprocess, deadlock, popen

I know this has been asked many times but my problem is different as I am using a third party code and cannot modify it too much.
I have a function that is called many times in the code to create a subprocess, write data to stdin and then read. It just hangs at this line

```
line = self.classifier.stderr.readline()
```

using popen.communicate did solve this problem but since func2(classifier, vectors) needs to be called multiple times, it throws an exception

```
  subprocess I/O operation on closed file
```

Is there a way to perform a non blocking read operation?

```
def func1 (extcmd):
                cmd=extcmd
                classifier = subprocess.Popen(self.classifier_cmd, shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE) 
                if self.classifier.poll():
                    raise OSError('Could not create classifier subprocess')
                return classifier

def func2(classifier, vectors):
                        classifier.stdin.write('\n'.join(vectors) + "\n\n")
                        lines = []
                        line = self.classifier.stderr.readline()
                        print("not reaching")
                        while (line.strip() != ''):
                #            print line
                            lines.append(line)
                            line = self.classifier.stderr.readline()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
                extcmd="some external shell script"
                vectors="some results"
                classifier=func1(extcmd)
                func2(classifier, vectors)
```

Modifying the code to add more details

```
import subprocess
import paths
import os.path

class CRFClassifier:
    def __init__(self, name, model_type, model_path, model_file, verbose):
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.name = name
        self.type = model_type
        self.model_fname = model_file
        self.model_path = model_path

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.model_path, self.model_fname)):
            print 'The model path %s for CRF classifier %s does not exist.' % (os.path.join(self.model_path, self.model_fname), name)
            raise OSError('Could not create classifier subprocess')


        self.classifier_cmd = '%s/crfsuite-stdin tag -pi -m %s -' % (paths.CRFSUITE_PATH, 
                             os.path.join(self.model_path, self.model_fname))
#        print self.classifier_cmd
        self.classifier = subprocess.Popen(self.classifier_cmd, shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

        if self.classifier.poll():
            raise OSError('Could not create classifier subprocess, with error info:\n%s' % self.classifier.stderr.readline())

        #self.cnt = 0


    def classify(self, vectors):
#        print '\n'.join(vectors) + "\n\n"

        self.classifier.stdin.write('\n'.join(vectors) + "\n\n")

        lines = []
        line = self.classifier.stderr.readline()
        while (line.strip() != ''):
#            print line
            lines.append(line)
            line = self.classifier.stderr.readline()


        if self.classifier.poll():
            raise OSError('crf_classifier subprocess died')

        predictions = []
        for line in lines[1 : ]:
            line = line.strip()
#            print line
            if line != '':
                fields = line.split(':')
#                print fields
                label = fields[0]
                prob = float(fields[1])
                predictions.append((label, prob))

        seq_prob = float(lines[0].split('\t')[1])

        return seq_prob, predictions


    def poll(self):
        """
        Checks that the classifier processes are still alive
        """
        if self.classifier is None:
            return True
        else:
            return self.classifier.poll() != None
```

A classifier object is created for an input file, which is a document with a list of sentences and at the time of creation it also executes the external command with this list of sentences. Then in a separate function  every sentence is processed giving a separate vector for each sentence. This new vector is passed to the classify function.

```
def func2():
    classifier=create a classifier object for an input file, this executes the external command
    for sentence in sentences:
        vectors=process(sentence)# some external function
        classifier.classify(features)
```

Comment: a shameless plug: you may find https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite useful; it should be easier than wrapping crfsuite command-line.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation? Looks like func1 exits with a return statement before func2 ever gets to do anything. Move everything starting from func2 one tab to the left and see what happens.Or, maybe the problem is elsewhere - you just did not paste your code correctly.

Comment: sorry, for that. I have formatted it properly now. I know the problem is due a deadlock but I cannot use communicate since func2 is called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your answer (from https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)? 
Note Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes.

Comment: Yes, I read and using communicate works for the first time, but func2 is called more than once and if I use communicate, it fails the second time with an error ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.  I am reading about select that can be used but I am not sure how can I use it without messing up things.

Answer (score 0):

You said you cannot change the code much, but maybe you can change it a little:) Try writing a block that finds out which "vector" is being used and use a different one.

Comment: I was reluctant to modify it too much as it's a big code base and I am not sure what effects it would have. Could you explain it a bit more or point to some example when you say about the vectors? I debugged the code and this is how it works. func1 executes a command with a list of sentences. Then func2 is called iteratively for every sentence input as vector to read the results. Hence it works for first sentence if I use communicate and then fails with an error.

Comment: How is "cmd" used in func1?

Comment: OK, it's getting a little too deep. I will just give you give my last 2 cents here. You are saying the problem arises when you call func2 more than once and get an error. I would just add a check if a file is used by  another process (that's how I interpret "closed" in the error message - maybe due to GIL) and if it is, try to create a deep copy and discard it later. Sorry, I don't think I can offer more - good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it